# How to set the first option as the selected in the SELECT form via hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

I have created a Views with an exposed filter and I tried to use hook_form_alter to convert it to a select list. Now, I need to set the default value as the first option whatever output in the select list. I DONT'T need to have '-Any-' as the default value which usually do. I wonder how can I achieve this. The page keep showing the below message when first visit the page not until one of the option is selected and applied.

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site
>   administrator.

Here the code in my template.php. Hope you can help me out. Thanks!

```
if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-news-page') { 

     //Query
     $query = db_select('node', 'n');
     $query->fields('n', array('title'));
     $query->condition('n.type', 'news');
     $query->orderby('n.title', 'ASC');
     $result = $query->execute();

     // Get Select options 
     $options = array();  

     foreach( $result as $node ){
       $options[$node->title] = $node->title;
     }


    // Alter the form
        $form['title_1'] = array(
         '#type' => 'select',
         //'#default_value' => ??
         '#options' => $options,
         '#title' => t('Filter By'), 
    ); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following code to your implementation of hook_form_alter():

```
if (empty($form_state['input']['title_1'])) {    
  // set the first element as default value
  $form_state['input']['title_1'] = reset($options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But by assigning $option[0] to the form, it threw me "Notice: Undefined offset: 0.."  I think mine is an associative array. Is there a way to get the value from the first associative array ?

Comment: Sure, you can 

`$form_state['input']['title_1'] = reset($options);`

Comment: That's exactly what I need. It works perfectly! You are awesome !